# Binomial Logistic Regression Plot interpretation (r plot)

Tags: r, regression, probability, logistic, residuals

I have built a logistic regression model to predict the amount of people likely to receive a Nobel Prize in science given "university attended, gpa earned, city, age, # of publications, awards received, and years of experience in the field" as predictors.

The problem (might be normal) out of 1800 entries only 2% have received the prize, thus making the 0 (no prize) excessively dominant.

My current probability regression plot:
[image]

Questions:

1- While this is understandable given the nature of the data set, is it normal ?
2- Can it be improved? alternatives ? suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: A few questions.  Your say you're modelling the amount of people to get a Nobel prize, but your title implies you are looking at propensity.  Can you clarify this?  Secondly, what do you mean my "improved"?  Logistic regression models the probability of an event occurring, and by the looks of your data far more people do not get a Nobel than do, so low estimates of probability to win are well within expectations.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. People to get/or not based off predictive variables. By improved I am simply asking if this plot ( which clearly represents the data set ) is the best way to go about problems like these. I am used to S curves when the data is more normally distributed. Fro your last points, I conclude you are agreeing that the plot is correct. I am just wondering it there is a better way to represent this, when the data is extremely skewed as in this case.

Comment: Because you're adjusting for multiple factors, this plot does not tell the whole story.  The model in the plot only adjusts for whatever is on the x axis. You could add several lines to demonstrate how modulating the other covariates changes the estimated line.